# how do I use the numbers from the list, to do the math equation in last 5 lines of code?

Tags: python-3.x, list, math

```
lope = []
def main():
    print('This program is going to do 5 calculations for growth rates      on FCF.')

    growth = .10

    freecash = int(input('What is initial free cash flow'))

    for i in range(5):
       freecash = freecash * (1+growth)
       lope.append(freecash)
    equation = freecash * (1+.03)

    print('The value in of Free cash in 5 years is: ',equation)

# this next part is for calculating the terminal
    print('This Calculates the terminal for you.')
    bwacc = float(input('Whats the WACC: '))
# ltg == Long Term Growth
    ltg = .03
    equation1 = equation * (1+ltg)/(bwacc-ltg)
    print('The Terminal Value is: ',equation1)

    one = lope[0] / (1+bwacc) ** 1
    two = lope[1] / (1+bwacc) ** 2
    three = lope[2] / (1+bwacc) ** 3
    four = lope[3] / (1+bwacc) ** 4
    five = lope[4] / (1+bwacc) ** 5
    print('The pv of perpetuity is: ',one, two,three,four,five)
```

This code is meant to calculate these 5 equations in the last 5 lines of code, I'm not really understanding how this isn't working when I put print statements.

Comment: Are you receiving errors? How isn't it working?

Comment: It only calculates lope[0] and prints that 5 times, theres no error when i run code. But i tried doing anything past lope[0] in the command line. And it says out of range.

Comment: You need to show the code *that isn't working*--the code with the print statements. Also show the desired output, actual output, and any tracebacks that result. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok for sure, thank you for the feed back. When im back to my computer, ill tweak the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a loop:

```
list4numbers = []
for i in range(5):
    a = lope[i] / (1+bwacc) ** i+1
    list4numbers.append(a)
```

With this you could do what ever you needed with the list. Hope I helped!

-Zeus

Comment: Tyvm, im gonna try that when i get back from walking dogs.